# std::vector of class containing atomic

Tags: c++, vector, copy, atomic, copy-constructor

I'm trying to create a vector containing instances of a class which, in turn, contains (among other things) std::atomic.

I've tried the several:

- if no copy constructor is specified, the compiler will give an error about the constructor being deleted.

If a copy constructor is specified, I've tried two things:

- with foo(foo& other) it will complain that no copy constructor was found for foo.

  Edit: the copy constructor is foo(foo& other) : atomic(other.atomic.load()) {}
- with foo(const foo& other) it will complain that there is no const copy constructor for std::atomic.

  Edit: the copy constructor is foo(const foo& other) : atomic(other.atomic.load()) {}

I have absolutely no clue on how to fix this, so any help is much appreciated

Comment: _" `std::atomic` is neither copyable nor movable."_ from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic.  You can however hold an a `std::unique_ptr<your_class>` in the vector.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do with your vector, please share a [MCVE]. `std::atomic` is not movable, so some `std::vector` operations are not available for that type.

Comment: If you have access to Boost libraries; you may wish to look into Boost::Intrusive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::atomic` is neither copyable nor movable, by design. Operations on `std::vector` which cause it to reallocate require its elements to be at least movable. So, you have the following options:

- Stop storing `std::atomic` in the element class. Perhaps a `std::unique_ptr<std::atomic>` could be used instead.
- Stop storing the element class directly in the vector, store `std::unique_ptr<ElementClass>` instead (as suggested by @Richard Critten in comments).
- Write a copy or move constructor and assignment operator for your class, which will somehow work around the non-movability of `std::atomic`.
- Give your class dummy copy/move operations to satisfy the compiler. Then, pre-allocate space in vector using `reserve`, and then only use functions which append elements (up to the preallocated size), access them, or delete from the end; no in-the-middle insertions or deletions. This way, the dummy operations will never actually be called.

  Given the fragility of this approach, I would suggest two precautions:

  1. Make the dummies throwing, so that you catch any violations of the "no resizing" requirement ASAP.
  2. Do not use `std::vector` directly, but wrap it in your own `NonResizableVector<T>` with a suitably restricted interface, and document it heavily.

Which one of these you should (or even can) use depends on what your class actually does.

Comment: The fourth bullet point looks like a huge maintenance cost. It would have to always be obvious that the vector should not ever be resized. Makes the codebase quite brittle, regarding reusability and maintenance. Maybe adding some extra warning about this in your answer?

Comment: I understand that std::atomic is non-copyable and non-moveable, however I simply wanted to implement the copy of the class that contains it in an improper way, as the reality is that I'm not gonna resize the vector - it is resized once at runtime from being empty to a certain size.
I was just wondering if I could implement some copy, such as doing, in the initializer list, atomic(other.atomic.load())
I have tried this but have gotten the errors mentioned above.

Comment: @Angew So basically my issue is that I was already trying to do nº3/4, but ran into the issues mentioned above in the (edited) original post.

Comment: @ZeroZ30o [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bec09ff53bdb79e). Please edit your question to show the code which actually fails for you.

Comment: @Angew my bad, it does work indeed and since the compiler was not giving the exact line of the error (gives an error inside "xmemory0" instead), I mistook it for another misuse of std::atomic.
Thanks a lot!